# Typeahead is not working with Jquery keyUp Function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I am newbie to typeahead.js and working on auto completion with bootstrap search box....my jquery works fine when i wanted to load data(option1,option2..etc)on document.ready.....here is the following code...

```
$(function() {
            function displayResult(item) {
                $('.alert').show().html('You selected <strong>' + item.value + '</strong>: <strong>' + item.text + '</strong>');
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                               type: 'GET',
                               url:'QuickSearch?City='+"Bengaluru",
                               dataType: 'json',
                               success: function(data){
                                   var j=jQuery.parseJSON(data.jsonAreaList);
                                   var cool=j;
                                 $('#demo1').typeahead({
                                     source: j,
                                    onSelect: displayResult
                                });

                                       },
                                       error: function(data) 
                                       {//When fails to load the Areas.

                                       }
                            });
                            return false;
                  });
```

All the areas are getting loaded properly....now my requirement is i dont want to load area on document.onready....like to take query from users and set result to typeahead textbox.....here is what i am trying

```
$(function() {
            function displayResult(item) {
                $('.alert').show().html('You selected <strong>' + item.value + '</strong>: <strong>' + item.text + '</strong>');
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#SearchBox").keyup(function() {
                 var city=$("#SearchBox").val();
                    $.ajax({
                               type: 'GET',
                               url:'QuickSearch?City='+city,
                               dataType: 'json',
                               success: function(data){
                                   var j=jQuery.parseJSON(data.jsonAreaList);
                                   var cool=j;
                                 $('#demo1').typeahead({
                                     source: j,
                                    onSelect: displayResult
                                });

                                       },
                                       error: function(data) 
                                       {//When fails to load the Areas.

                                       }
                            });
                            return false;
                  });
    });
});
```

I dont getting where i am doing wrong....:(

Answer (score 0):

Your url Query string in ajax call is wrong.

Try:

```
url:'QuickSearch?City='+city; //you have a typo in your code
```

Comment: Hey @noob in second example i am getting the result list(Json)...City is dynamic in second example....:)and one more thing bind function has no effects...:(

Comment: I know but can you see the spelling mistake 'city' for 'City' ??

Comment: is your code working now? Was that just the typo stopping it from working?

Comment: No noob...on alert i am able to see the json formated list...but something is wrong while assigning the source...:)